# Does rotation in plane involve Euclid's parallel postulate?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

It is given a line $l$, a point $P$ not on $l$, and $PQ$ perpendicular to $l$, i.e., $Q$ is on $l$. Let $R$ be a point on $l$ with $QR = PQ$. Therefore, $<PQR = 90^{\rm o}$.

I can't figure out if Euclid's parallel postulate is involved when I rotate the object $PQR$ clockwise by $90^{\rm o}$. Any hint or reference is highly appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand clearly what exactly you mean by "involved", but everything you did also works perfectly both in elliptic/spherical and hyperbolic geometry. Just rotate the sphere or the Minkowski hyperboloid/Poincare disk/Klein disk.

Comment: But the length of $PR$ will no longer be $\sqrt{2}$ times $PQ$, the points will no longer move $\frac{\pi}{2}$ times $PQ$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite positive rotation does not involve Euclid's fifth postulate. I'll try to present strict definition of rotation in synthetic setting.

**Definition 1**. An ordered pair $(A,B)$ of halflines having the same origin will be called a directed angle. Also denote $AB:=(A,B)$

**Definition 2**. We introduce a relation $\simeq$ among directed angles: We say $AB\simeq CD$ iff these angles are congruent (or equivalently have the same measure) and have the same orientation (in case $AB$ and $CD$ are not $0$ or $180$ degrees). Having the same orientation roughly speaking means that going from $A$ to $B$ and from $C$ to $D$ are both clockwise or both counterclockwise.

It can be proven that

**Proposition 1**. $\simeq$ is an equivalence relation.

**Proposition 2**. Given a halfline $A$ of origin $o$ and a directed angle $PQ$, there is a unique halfline $B$ of origin $o$ such that $AB\simeq PQ$.

Now if we fix a directed angle $PQ$ and a point $o$ on a plane, we can define a rotation around $o$ by a directed angle $PQ$ the following way: Obviously we map $o$ to $o$. Take $a\neq o$. By proposition 2 we can find a halfline $B$ of origin $o$ such that $AB\simeq PQ$, where $A$ is a halfline $\overrightarrow{oa}$. Next we find a unique point $b$ on $B$ such that $oa\equiv ob$. Finally we map $a$ to $b$.

What is the most important thing about rotations is that it can be proven in neutral geometry that they are isometries. It follows quite easily from lemma

**Lemma**. Let halflines $P,Q,P_1,Q_1$ all have the same origin. If $PP_1\simeq QQ_1$, then $PQ\simeq P_1Q_1$.

To prove that rotations are isometries you have to consider few cases but basically you apply the lemma and SAS congruence rule.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. However, if you downrated my answer, I am disappointed. In fact, the paper that I attached contains a proposition that rotation involves the fifth postulate. See section 8.

Comment: Well, it wasn't me who downrated your answer. As for the paper and lemma 8.1 (if that is the proposition you have in mind): The paper is not about standard axiomatic development of geometry and I looked at it from such point, but  honestly speaking I think the author is wrong in his remark that Euclid 5 in only needed in rotating the point at the beginning of the proof (in fact my construction shows that it is not needed). The moment he uses Euclid 5 is in lemma 5.24 as it is well known that Playfair's axiom is equivalent to Euclid 5 assuming all neutral geometry axioms.

Comment: thank you very much. I will review your proof and let you know if I understand it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that rotation indeed involves Euclids fifth postulate. Section 8 of [this paper](http://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/ConstructiveGeometryAndTheParallelPostulate.pdf) is all about that.